# Strange problem after override getResources() to make textsize dont change with system settings

Tags: java, android, text-size

The goal was to make textsize in app dont change with system settings.
I found to override getResources() in activity and override attachBaseContext() in fragment.Like the code below:

```
@Override
public Resources getResources() {
    Resources resources = super.getResources();
    Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
    config.setToDefaults();
    return createConfigurationContext(config).getResources();
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    Configuration config = newBase.getResources().getConfiguration();
    config.fontScale=1;
    Context context=newBase.createConfigurationContext(config);
    super.attachBaseContext(context);
}
```

After I added these code,I found some strange crash start to appear.Crash info:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in 
com.xx.xx:layout/default_loading: Binary XML file line #9 in 
com.xx.xx:layout/default_loading: Error inflating class android.widget.ProgressBar
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in 
com.xx.xx:layout/default_loading: Error inflating class android.widget.ProgressBar
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:774)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1138)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1099)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
at com.jianzhiku.activity.HomeActivity.onCreateView(HomeActivity.java:432)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1971)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:311)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:249)
at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25960)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:995)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7112)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7112)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25960)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7112)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:830)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25960)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2625)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2888)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2345)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9046)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1066)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:889)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:816)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1051)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8262)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: locale == null
at libcore.icu.LocaleData.get(LocaleData.java:242)
at java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(NumberFormat.java:840)
at java.text.NumberFormat.getPercentInstance(NumberFormat.java:548)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.formatStateDescription(ProgressBar.java:1580)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:312)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:262)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:258)
... 58 more
```

Here is the layout/default_loading:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="8dp">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/prograssbar"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loading_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="loading..."
    android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I'm sure before override getResources() in activity and attachBaseContext(Context newBase) in fragment,this crash dont exist.And I tested to remove these override,crash dont happen anymore.

I asked some other guys,they didnt have this problem.

Why this crash happens?And how to fix this?

My app structure is like this:
First Open a splashactivity then finish and open mainactivity,mainactivity contains a viewpager+fragment with 4 fragments.
Other function start activity from fragment.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is when you override `getResources` and create the configuration from a context that is not locale aware, hence the crash you get. I rarely stop to say things like this in stackoverflow since its main purpose is to teach. However a lot of it also encourages others to copy your approach and I cannot stress enough that you should NOT do this. There are a lot of people that require apps to adjust to this setting in order to be able to use them. Not all of us have 20-20 vision. Perhaps the better approach would be to reconsider the design.

Comment: Thanks.I'll check the lifecycle.Change design is not the decision I can make.